# Django: OperationalError at /admin/

Tags: python, django

So I ran my program based on from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/) and It worked without any error. I go to to /admin. I login. So far everything is good. Then when it loads I get this:

[image: Error Code]

I checked the traceback (which is really long) and none of includes my code. It doesn't tell me what part of the code this error is occurring in so I don't know how to approach this. Please explain what this is, why this is happening, and how I can fix it.

**If you need any part of my code, just ask in comments because I don't know where this is happening.**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to run migrate command in-order to force django to create auth tables.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then for any change you made on models, don't forget to run these two commands.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip install django==2.1.5`

If the problem persists,

Use `python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`

Comment: man you are freaking god i was literally stuck at this for hours and then boom it ran it runs OMG !! getting tears in eyes thank you so much 

Answer (score 1):

- by default, the auth table is not created in the database
- so first we need to create the table and reload the page

to achieve the same

make the migrations by typing the following command

```
        1. python3 manage.py makemigrations
        2. python3 manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Till the time they don't debug this issue with Django and Sqlite3 use the older versions of Django 
You may consider using version 1.10.5(using command pip install --upgrade django==1.10.5)

Answer (score 0):

yes, that was fault of django version ,when i installed django==2.1.5 that problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest django version

```
$ pip3 install django==2.2.8
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

then reload page in browser

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem with migration just type the following command:-

python manage.py migrate

Answer (score -1):

If you still get error after you lunched

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and for every change you made on models

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Then check if you have Django version older than 2.1.5, because this latter version fixes a bug returning "OperationalError>no such table" when adding an object to your database as superuser.
So try to

```
pip install Django==2.1.5
```

However, you will have to re-write your project anew.

Comment: A good trick to avoid rewriting the whole project is to copy and paste the text from the files you edited, so I expect they are "admin, model, urls (#yourapp, #yourprojectinnerdirectory), settings". then cpoy paste the templates directory and in the end replace all #yourprojectoldname with #yourprojectnewname from manage.py and settings.py.
 in the end don't forget to migrate, makemigratinos and create superuser agian.

Answer (score -1):

[user permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqSDY.png)

Hi
In Django Administration :check if the user has the right permission, it should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

use these commands

python3 manage.py makemigrations

python3 manage.py migrate

python3 manage.py runserver

Comment: This question is over 6 years old. It has several existing answers, many of which mention `makemigrations` and `migrate`. Are you _entirely sure_ that this answer introduces something new? If so, please [edit] to clarify. Otherwise, please avoid leaving duplicate answers.

Comment: Also, instead of asking people to run commands blindly, please always explain what they do and why they should be used. SO is about _learning_, not copy-and-pasting.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the sqlite database and migrations files then run this

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate